# pass custom variables when connecting a gtk widget

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I've a Gtk.switch, and I want to connect it to a function, but I want that function to get another variable to do her job... :

```
    switch = Gtk.Switch()
    switch.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_stream)

def on_switch_stream(self,switch, gparam):
    print "switch=%s stream=%s" % (switch,gparam)
```

But it seems, that the "connect" method, doesn't allow that...What is the way to pass some information to the function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it as another argument. The `connect` method accepts an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
    switch.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_stream, your_variable)

def on_switch_stream(self, switch, gparam, your_variable):
    print "switch=%s stream=%s" % (switch,gparam)
```

Comment: Pretty simple, but I wasn't able to find it by myself... many thanks !